# How modifying the width of xticks line in a barplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the following plot[image: plot]

The code for obtaining it is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{a.dat}
    experiment,1,2,3,4,5
    V1-01,0.14,0.25,0.12,0.13,0.12
    V1-02,0.08,0.07,0.12,0.13,0.12
    V1-03,0.10,0.19,0.14,0.15,0.15
    V2-01,0.11,0.23,0.08,0.10,0.09
    V2-02,0.10,0.20,0.20,0.21,0.21
    MH-03,0.16,0.18,0.21,0.21,0.19
    MH-04,0.26,0.28,0.30,0.30,0.29
    MH-05,0.37,0.41,0.40,0.41,0.39
    MH-05,0.37,0.41,0.40,0.42,0.36
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{a.dat}\a

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=9.5cm, height=5.5cm,
legend style={legend columns=-1, font=\tiny},
legend pos= north west,
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\a}{experiment},
xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,rotate=0},
ybar,
ybar interval=0.6,
enlargelimits=false,
ymin=0,ymax=0.45,
ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8},
yticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=2
}]
\addplot [color=blue,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={1}] \a;
\addplot [color=yellow,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={2}]\a;
\addplot [color=red,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={3}] \a;
\addplot [color=green,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={4}] \a;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase the width of the gray line that is used for separating     data, e. g. V1-01 and V1-02 ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your recommandation. I have editing the question with a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{a.dat}
        experiment,1,2,3,4,5
        V1-01,0.14,0.25,0.12,0.13,0.12
        V1-02,0.08,0.07,0.12,0.13,0.12
        V1-03,0.10,0.19,0.14,0.15,0.15
        V2-01,0.11,0.23,0.08,0.10,0.09
        V2-02,0.10,0.20,0.20,0.21,0.21
        MH-03,0.16,0.18,0.21,0.21,0.19
        MH-04,0.26,0.28,0.30,0.30,0.29
        MH-05,0.37,0.41,0.40,0.41,0.39
        MH-05,0.37,0.41,0.40,0.42,0.36
    \end{filecontents*}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{a.dat}\a
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=9.5cm,
        height=5.5cm,
        legend style={legend columns=-1, font=\tiny},
        legend pos= north west,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\a}{experiment},
        xticklabel style={font=\tiny,rotate=0},
        ybar,
        ybar interval=0.6,
        enlargelimits=false,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.45,
        ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=2
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        xtick pos=lower,
        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=5mm,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % (moved common options here)
        table/x expr=\coordindex,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot [fill,color=blue]   table [fill,y={1}] \a;
        \addplot [fill,color=yellow] table [fill,y={2}] \a;
        \addplot [fill,color=red]    table [fill,y={3}] \a;
        \addplot [fill,color=green]  table [fill,y={4}] \a;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: @mbrossar, does my answer solve your question or do you need further assistance? In the first case, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).